# Is it possible read pixels from a jpeg file determenistically across all platforms?

Tags: python, c, opencv, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I've encountered an issue where I've found that the pixels in a JPEG image might vary slightly depending on the computer I'm using to read them. I'm mainly a Python programmer, and I'd prefer using opencv to read my images, but I'm not opposed to doing something using PIL or reading the image in C.

According to this post
[JPEG images have different pixel values across multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565889/jpeg-images-have-different-pixel-values-across-multiple-devices)

different decoders are allowed to vary their output slightly, so I have a feeling that the answer to my question is no. But I'd figured I'd explicitly ask it anyway just in case I'm misunderstanding something, or it is an issue where I have to ensure that opencv is built against the same version of the a specific jpeg library.

Is there a way I can read a jpeg file (preferably using opencv) in a way that I get the same pixel values on any platform I run my code on?

Comment: You could decode the jpeg manually?

Comment: no. - opencv might be even compiled against different jpeg libs on different systems. avoid jpg images for anything computer-vision related, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice, no. Pixels may differ between different versions of the same library, or even the same version of the same library between platforms.

In theory, you will get the same pixels values if you use the *exact* same algorithm/software on all platforms you need to support. But I think this means you'll either have to write the decoder yourself, or at least read a lot of source code and configure and compile a known library yourself.