# Skimage Python reads different Pixel-Values from Picture than Java/Photoshop

Tags: python, java, image, pixel, scikit-image

I want to read the same values from a picture in Python and Java.
In python, i use skimage's imread, in Java i use ImageIO.read().

I expect that the two results are pixel-wise equal, but they are not. Photoshop displays the same values as Javas ImageIO, but skimage's result is different.

Here are the lines for Java:

```
BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("/Users/.../Downloads/model/input/123456789.jpg"));
bi.getData().getPixel(10,100,new int[3]) //result = [102, 121, 128]
```

And here for Python:

```
image = io.imread("/Users/.../Downloads/model/input/123456789.jpg")
image[10][100] #result = [109, 126, 133]
```

My input Image is RGB and has a sRGB profile. I tried attaching different profiles or removing it completely, without success. I also tried using different libraries for Java(like https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) and/or Python... I tried converting to PNG **before** reading it, but the two results are never truly equal. Why is that?

Here is the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FEWYS4HNZ-SpYCQBx0gQIt-662yjxLfV/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am no expert on this, but I thought that with JPG images, there is no such thing as pixel-perfection, that it uses a lossy compression, and when image files are decompressed, and an image is extracted, no two images will be exactly alike.

Comment: As stated, this also affects png's

Comment: What do you mean by "I tried converting to png" though? This remains unclear.

Comment: I opened the image in photoshop, stored it as a new png file and opened that n java/python.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27415320/1428606

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

When reading with skimage in python, i get a HxWxC image, but with ImageIO.read() in Java, i get a WxHxC image.