# Why does tensorflow decode jpeg images differently from scipy imread?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, scipy

`tf.image.decode_jpeg()` function of Tensorflow gives  different numerical result than `scipy.misc.imread()` for `jpg` images. While the images look similar, pixel values are different.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def minimal_example():
    def _bytes_feature(value):
        return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

    tffilename = 'astronaut.tfrecords'
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(tffilename)
    #image_source = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Astronaut-EVA.jpg'
    image_path = 'astronaut.jpg'
    image_file = open(image_path,'rb')
    image = image_file.read()
    image_scipy = scipy.misc.imread(image_path)
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={'image':_bytes_feature(image)}))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()

    record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=tffilename)
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(next(record_iterator))
    image = example.features.feature['image'].bytes_list.value[0]
    image_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image).eval(session=tf.Session())
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
    ax1.imshow(image_scipy)
    ax2.imshow(image_tf)
    print('Reconstruction Error', np.sum(np.abs(image_tf - image_scipy)))
    plt.show()
```

result:

```
Reconstruction Error 3420883624
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discrepancy arises because of inaccurate, but fast, default Discrete Cosine Tranform used by Tensorflow

According to the [Source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e073322452e41e76754314aa75d543d071003fc5/tensorflow/core/kernels/decode_image_op.cc#L109)

> // The TensorFlow-chosen default for jpeg decoding is IFAST, sacrificing
>
> // image quality for speed.
>
> flags_.dct_method = JDCT_IFAST;

In order to get accurate decoding one can set the attribute `dct_method = 'INTEGER_ACCURATE'` as show in example below

```
def minimal_example():
    #image_source = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/88/Astronaut-EVA.jpg'
    image_path = 'astronaut.jpg'
    image_file = open(image_path,'rb')
    image_raw = image_file.read()
    image_scipy = scipy.misc.imread(image_path)
    image_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw).eval(session=tf.Session())
    image_tf_accurate = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_raw,dct_method="INTEGER_ACCURATE").eval(session=tf.Session())
    print('Error For Default: ', np.sum(np.abs(image_tf - image_scipy)))
    print('Error For Accurate: ', np.sum(np.abs(image_tf_accurate - image_scipy)))
    #Error For Default:  3420883624
    #Error For Accurate:  0
```

Answer (score 2):

[The JPEG standard does not require bit-to-bit identical decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23714501/1735003). So, some variations are expected between different implementations.

However, it still requires

> a maximum 1 bit of difference for each pixel component.

So both outputs should not be apart further than one. Right?

```
print('max diff: ', np.max(np.abs(image_tf.astype(float) - image_scipy.astype(float))))
# max diff:  17.0
```

Ouch, at least one implementation does not follow the standard...

Comment: First time i hear that. Very interesting! scipy seems to use libjpeg-dev (through PIL/Pillow), while tensorflow might use [libjpeg-turbo](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4807).