# Images opened in Pillow and OpenCV are not equivelant

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I downloaded a test image from Wikipedia (the tree seen below) to compare `Pillow` and `OpenCV` (using `cv2`) in python. Perceptually the two images appear the same, but their respective `md5` hashes don't match; and if I subtract the two images the result is not even close to solid black (the image shown below the original). The original image is a JPEG. If I convert it to a PNG first, the hashes match.

The last image shows the frequency distribution of how the pixel value differences.

As Catree pointed out my subtraction was causing integer overflow. I updated to converting too `dtype=int` before the subtraction (to show the negative values) and then taking the absolute value before plotting the difference. Now the difference image is perceptually solid black.

This is the code I used:

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import sys
import md5
import numpy as np

def hashIm(im):
    imP = np.array(Image.open(im))

    # Convert to BGR and drop alpha channel if it exists
    imP = imP[..., 2::-1]
    # Make the array contiguous again
    imP = np.array(imP)
    im = cv2.imread(im)

    diff = im.astype(int)-imP.astype(int)

    cv2.imshow('cv2', im)
    cv2.imshow('PIL', imP)
    cv2.imshow('diff', np.abs(diff).astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.imshow('diff_overflow', diff.astype(np.uint8))

    with open('dist.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        diff = im-imP
        for i in range(-256, 256):
            outfile.write('{},{}\n'.format(i, np.count_nonzero(diff==i)))

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    return md5.md5(im).hexdigest() + '   ' + md5.md5(imP).hexdigest()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print sys.argv[1] + '\t' + hashIm(sys.argv[1])
```

---

[image: Original photo of a tree (from Wikipedia "Tree" article)]

Frequency distribution updated to show negative values.

[image: Updated difference]

---

This is what I was seeing before I implemented the changes recommended by Catree.

[image: Difference]

[image: Dist]

Comment: i may be wrong, but i think you may be suffering from rounding errors here `np.array(Image.open(im))` and iirc imshow stretches the colors to meet the range (look at the actual values of `im-imP` they are likely to be very small)

Comment: I just [tried](https://i.imgur.com/f0gkpD8.jpg) it, but no differences here (win10 + python3.6 + opencv-python==3.4.0.12 + Pillow==5.1.0).

Comment: @Nullman Interesting idea, but i'm not sure what you mean by rounding errors. `np.array(Image.open(im))` gives a `dtype=np.uunt8`. I posted a graph of the distribution of values in `im-imP`.

Comment: since joost managed to run it without issues, perhaps something indeed is different in your version of those libraries. what versions are you using?

Comment: @Joost Interesting... It's possible the image was re-encoded when I uploaded it to SO. Do you mind trying it [with the original](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg) if you didn't already?

Comment: @Nullman I'm on Ubuntu 16.04, Python2.7.12, opencv-2.4.9.1, opencv-python 3.4.0.12, numpy 1.14.2, Pillow 5.1.0. I'm in a `virtualenv` so at least the python libs should be up to date.

Comment: i ran the code as well (these 2 lines are backwards! `im = cv2.imread(im)
    imP = np.array(Image.open(im))`
and it works fine for me, i got cv2 version 3.3.0 and pillow 4.3.0 on python 3.6.3 on win10

Comment: @Nullman Well I'll be...that's what I get for trying to make my post prettier. I edited with an identical copy `cat chck.py` now, which has them in the right order. It's interesting that both of you are on Win10. I'll see if I can try it on a Windows box tonight.

Comment: i think the major difference here is that both of us are on python3

Comment: I did use both the one uploaded to SO and from wikipedia, but both showed the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The original image is a JPEG.

JPEG decoding can produce different results depending on the libjpeg version, compiler optimization, platform, etc.

Check which version of libjpeg `Pillow` and `OpenCV` are using.

See this answer for more information: [JPEG images have different pixel values across multiple devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23714501/6055233) or [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10641).

BTW, `(im-imP)` produces `uint8` overflow (there is no way to have such a high amount of large pixel differences without seeing it in your [frequency chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5zdS.png)). Try to cast to `int` type before doing your frequency computation.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that about JPEG. I updated my frequency chart to use `int`. Turns out all the values of `im-imP != 0` are negative. I haven 't found the exact versions yet but my `OpenCV` is pretty old and it's using built in sources for `libjpeg`